Can one think in a programming language?
I asked this in the Python StackOverflow, but it got closed. I'm really curious if this is possible, so hopefully this board is a bit more open minded.
Some exposition to explain the title: my native language is Russian, and after I learned English I continued to have my internal monologue in Russian. It was only after a few years of living in America that my internal monologue switched over to English, and then I considered myself as thinking in English.
All of that is to say: for professional programmers: is your internal monologue when you program happening in your programming language? Or do you think in your speaking language and translate commands into code by remembering the appropriate keywords?
I’ve never programmed in a language enough to switch over my internal monologue, but I would like to. For those who succeeded, were there any particular practices you engaged in? Or does it just come down to coding a lot and reviewing code?

Similar to: Can I teach my brain to understand binary?

A difference with StackOverflow is that scientific sites require at least some background research; at this time your definition of 'can one think' is not defined; without at least a proper definition of the key terms in your Q, every answer posted, if any, will end up in discussions because the answer will not be satisfactory; the only way to get to-the-point, specific answers is by asking to-the-point, specific questions with well-founded terminologies.....

Ideally, your post should contain a link or two to sites that helped you, but where your own search on the topic got stuck. This helps people find direction.

In programming, first we understand the problem then we convert it into a flowchart then we write the codes.
